# Obtaining confidence interval for npreg as values, not as plot

Tags: r

I am using the well known "np" package of Hayfield & Racine for non-parametric regressions. It allows *plotting* confidence bands for the estimated coefficient based on bootstrap procedures. See the code below for an example.

**Question**: I am wondering how to obtain these confidence intervalls in numerical form? One, but not the only reason for this question is that I really don't like the presentation of the ci's. More generally speaking, I would like to use and further process the confidence band within my analysis.

```
   library(np)
   # generate random variables:
   x <- 1:100 + rnorm(100)/2
   y <- (1:100)^(0.25)  + rnorm(100)/2
   mynp <- npreg(y~x)
   plot(mynp, plot.errors.method="bootstrap")`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when executing `plot`, the function is calling to the plot method of `np` package which is the function `npplot`

`npplot` exepts an argument `plot.behavior` which equals to `plot` by default which plots the results and returns `NULL`. you should set `plot.behavior = "plot-data"`, and the function will plot and return the data of the object.

```
dat <- plot(mynp, plot.errors.method="bootstrap",plot.behavior = "plot-data")
```

Than the values in the line can be accesed through `dat$r1$mean` and the values to be added to the mean to get the upper and lower ci accesed through `dat$r1$merr`.

notice that not all value are plotted. only half of them (every other value and than the last).

read the 'help' on `npplot` for more options.

further is an example of the use of the code and the results:

```
library(np)
# generate random variables:
x <- 1:100 + rnorm(100)/2
y <- (1:100)^(0.25)  + rnorm(100)/2
mynp <- npreg(y~x)
dat <- plot(mynp, plot.errors.method="bootstrap",plot.behavior = "plot-data")
```

[image]

Then recreating the results:

```
z <- unlist(dat$r1$eval,use.names = F)
CI.up = as.numeric(dat$r1$mean)+as.numeric(dat$r1$merr[,2])
CI.dn = as.numeric(dat$r1$mean)+as.numeric(dat$r1$merr[,1])
plot(dat$r1$mean~z, cex=1.5,xaxt='n', ylim=c(1.0,3.5),xlab='',ylab='lalala!', main='blahblahblah',col='blue',pch=16)
arrows(z,CI.dn,z,CI.up,code=3,length=0.2,angle=90,col='red')
```

we will get:
[image]

As you can see, theresults are the same (only I have calculated the intervals for each point and not only for half of them).

note the `plot.errors.type` attribute for `npplot` which gets "standard" and "quantiles" and is "standard" at default. When you specify "standard" `dat$r1$merr` will keep the standard errors and the plot will include mean+std err as intervals. Alternatively the plot will include the quantiles as the intervals and the quantiles will be saved at `dat$r1$merr`. which quntiles to use are specified by `plot.errors.quantiles` quantiles and it's only relevant if  `plot.errors.type = "quantiles"`

Comment: Great thanks! That was straight forward! So I am just wondering why this was so hard to find, e.g. searching the documentation for "confidence" did not yield any result that suggested the data could be retrieved.

There is one issue however: If I understood the documentation correctly now, $merr retrieves the standard error, NOT a confidence bound. So 5% confidence intervals would be the mean +/- 1.9559*dat$r1$merr ?

Comment: Great! Thanks for further details!

Comment: I will upvote the answer, but I can't yet accept because you did not specify that the values you take are standard errors. They are NOT usual confidence bounds at 5% (or any other level of) significance. These bounds should be much wider, right? In case of normality, you would have to multiply the standard error by ~1.96. Here, we have bootstraps due to non-normality, so it would be most appropriate to obtain the 2.5 and the 97.5 percentile from the bootstrapped distribution. Correct? But I can't find a way to acces these bootstraps from the data. But maybe this requires a new question

Comment: set `plot.errors.type = "quntiles"` and than `merr` will keep the quntiles. see the updated answer

Comment: Is there a way to know which points are statistically significant?